# How to map Json Array without KVC in RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I am having json response as below:

```
[
  {
    "DateOfBirth": "1951-08-02T00:00:00",
    "Age": "65",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "FirstName": "abc",
    "LastName": "xyz"
  }
]
```

It does not have any key in the top level.

```
RKObjectMapping *entityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyEntityModel class]];
[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"DateOfBirth": @"dateOfBirth",
            @"Age": @"age",
            @"Gender": @"gender",
            @"FirstName": @"firstName",
            @"LastName": @"lastName"
    }];

RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:patientMatchingMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:code];
```

This doesn't map the objects and has null mapping in entity class. How to map such response?

Comment: it's an array of dictionaries in the JSON. what do you mean `has null mapping in entity class`?

Comment: This is the mapping result : <RKMappingResult: 0x7fb354e702f0, results={
    "<null>" =     (
        "<MyEntityModel: 0x7fb352df5c20>",
        "<MyEntityModel: 0x7fb352d736d0>"
    );
}>    Where in all the values inside MyEntityModel are nil.

Comment: how are you testing the values (instance variables) in the entity instances in the array? your mapping looks ok (though you didn't show your entity class definition...)